# Ruby : Generate a Hash of Hashes from an Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following

```
friends = [{ name: "Jack", attr1:"def", attr2:"def" }, { name: "Jill", attr1:"def", attr2:"def" }]
```

I want to convert the above representation into a hash of hashes like this

```
friends = { "Jack" => { attr1: "def", attr2:"def" }, "Jill" => { attr1: "def", attr2: "def" } }
```

Any elegant way of doing this in Ruby ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Hash[friends.map { |f| _f = f.dup; [_f.delete(:name), _f] }]
# => {"Jack"=>{:attr1=>"def", :attr2=>"def"}, "Jill"=>{:attr1=>"def", :attr2=>"def"}}
```

Comment: you still would need to remove name from the attribute :-)

Comment: @tokland To fix this you could change it to `Hash[friends.map { |f| [f.delete(:name), f] }]`

Comment: Sorry, but IMHO `delete` is a no-no, now the input hash is also modified, an algorithm should not do that.

Comment: Good point — I added a `dup` call so that each iteration works off a clone of the data. Why do you say `delete` is bad here?

Comment: @HansEngel: `delete` is generally bad because it's an imperative/destructive operation, functional/declarative programming usually makes code easier to understand and reason about. Ruby has no non-destructive delete, that's why active_record introduced `Hash#except`.

Comment: Is there alternative to the Hash[] syntax? Because it doesn't look so elegant when the block spans multiple lines.

Answer (score 3):

```
friends.each_with_object({}) do |f, o|
    f = f.dup
    o[f.delete :name] = f
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hash = {}
friends.each{|h| hash[h.delete(:name)] = h }
# => {"Jack"=>{:attr1=>"def", :attr2=>"def"}, "Jill"=>{:attr1=>"def", :attr2=>"def"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to transform one array into another, use `collect`:

```
friends = Hash[
  friends.collect do |f|
    _f = f.dup
    name = _f.delete(:name)
    [ name, _f ]
  end
]
```

You can create a new hash easily using `Hash[]` and provide it an array with a series of key/value pairs in it. In this case the `name` field is removed from each.

Answer (score 1):

If we understand "elegant" as the way to write concise code by leveraging reusable abstractions, I'd write:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
require 'facets/hash'
friends.mash { |f| [f[:name], f.except(:name)] }
```

No need to add gem dependencies for these two fairly big libraries, you can always implement the individual methods in your extensions library.